# Creating rich text element for Sitecore Forms

Tags: sitecore-client, sitecore-forms

I have created a new component for the Sitecore Forms called "Rich Text", with the aim to have "Rich Text" capabilities while working with forms. Everything works as expected.

[image]

Apart from one thing, the WYSIWYG editor is missing, however, I sort of can see that Sitecore actually tries to add it when I inspect the code via dev tools.

[image]

Template setup:

[image]

Text field setup from `/sitecore/client/Applications/FormsBuilder/Components/Layouts/PropertyGridForm/PageSettings/Settings/RichText/Details/Text` based on template "FormTextArea Parameters".

And rendering item id is set to TextArea.

[image]

Have I done something wrong or is that simply not doable?